# Разъясните условие задачи

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Очередной раз ломаю голову не над кодом, а над тем, что от меня тут хотят:

Создать класс в ортодоксальной канонической форме, отображающий механический счётчик. Счётчик может принимать значения от 0 до 999. У счетчика есть две кнопки – «+» и «с». При нажатии кнопки «+» счётчик переходит в следующее состояние:

1. если его значение от 0 до 998, то значение увеличится на единицу;
2. если его значение 999, то его значение станет равным 0.

При нажатии кнопки «с» значение счетчика становится равным 0.
В классе должны быть функции-члены:

1. конструктор, имеющий аргумент – начальное значение;
2. функция, моделирующая нажатие кнопки «+»;
3. функция, моделирующая нажатие кнопки «с»;
4. функция, возвращающая значение счётчика.

Функции при получении некорректных аргументов должны выдавать предупреждение. 
Перегрузить операторы вставки в поток и извлечения из потока так, чтобы они извлекали и вставляли объекты класса в потоки, ассоциированные с двоичными файлами.

Непонятна эта строчка, что тут от меня хотят:

> Чтобы они извлекали и вставляли
> объекты класса в потоки,
> ассоциированные с двоичными файлами.

Ну что тут зашифровано?

Comment: Сериализация? о.0

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что под **объектами класса** подразумеваются строчки ввода и вывода программы и имеется в виду, что на Винде потоки должны быть не text, а binary. Т.е. например fopen("xaxa","r") откроет файл xaxa на чтение в *текстовом* режиме, а fopen("xaxa,"rb") в *binary*.

Но это только предположение.

PS. setmode() в Винде (MinGW) позволяет менять режим потока.

```
 #include  <fcntl.h>

  setmode (1,O_BINARY);  // переключить stdout 
  setmode (fileno(stdin),O_TEXT); // переключить stdin
```